# Software raid is slowing my server

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

My server is showing high average load, and after investigation I found that there is a lot of IO caused by raid.

Server uses i7 3770 processor, 32GB ram and 2x3TB disks with CentOS7 and software raid setup.

```
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sda3[1] sdb3[0]
      1073610752 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [===============>.....]  check = 77.3% (830580032/1073610752) finish=333.7min speed=12133K/sec
      bitmap: 4/8 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : active raid1 sda4[1] sdb4[0]
      1839090112 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 3/14 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[1] sdb1[0]
      16760832 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=DELAYED

md1 : active raid1 sda2[1] sdb2[0]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=DELAYED

unused devices: <none>
```

This check has started automatically and 54% when I noticed it was before 12 hours. I have checked disk health, and my server provider has tested them 2 days ago also because I have been convinced that disk are causing my server to have high average load.

When I check which processes are delayed I get this, and each time I run it one of raid processes is there

```
[root@server ~]# top -b -n 1 | awk '{if (NR <=7) print; else if ($8 == "D") {print; count++} } END {print "Total status D (I/O wait probably): "count}'
top - 08:38:38 up 1 day, 16:23,  3 users,  load average: 6.33, 6.32, 6.22
Tasks: 288 total,   2 running, 280 sleeping,   4 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.9 us,  0.7 sy,  0.3 ni, 76.6 id, 18.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32460092 total,   265352 free,  7304544 used, 24890196 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16760828 total, 16727480 free,    33348 used. 24434784 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    387 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.0  0.0   0:24.48 kworker/u16:4
    545 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.0  0.0   1:14.82 jbd2/md2-8
 449624 root      25   5       0      0      0 D   0.0  0.0   5:48.69 md2_resync
Total status D (I/O wait probably): 3
```

Is this normal behavior, is this software or hardware problem?

I am suspecting that it is slowing my server because when I check top processes, there is no process with too much CPU consumption, and load averages are almost always above 6.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 899323 mysql     20   0 30.285g 4.844g   9304 S   1.7 15.6  86:07.46 mysqld
    477 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:09.68 md0_raid1
   3359 root      30  10  277464  33136   2712 S   0.7  0.1  12:37.91 python2.7
 310858 mailnull  20   0   77356   7824   3856 D   0.7  0.0   0:00.03 exim
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   1:42.94 rcuos/0
    407 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:08.27 kworker/+
    625 root      20   0   94284  53560  53372 S   0.3  0.2   1:32.82 systemd-+
   3504 root      20   0  216748  27800   5324 S   0.3  0.1   1:10.35 httpd
 309919 nobody    20   0  217164  25440   2680 S   0.3  0.1   0:00.04 httpd
```

right now after this top command this is result of uptime

```
[root@server ~]# uptime
 17:47:19 up 2 days,  1:32,  1 user,  load average: 5.87, 6.23, 6.06
```

UPDATE

Here are results from raid checking

```
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sda3[1] sdb3[0]
      1073610752 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 4/8 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : active raid1 sda4[1] sdb4[0]
      1839090112 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 11/14 pages [44KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[1] sdb1[0]
      16760832 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[1] sdb2[0]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Can I do something to fix it?

Comment: Is your server slow? Your question says software RAID is slowing your server, but your question doesn't mention that your server is slow or performing poorly.

Comment: I have added info about cpu consumption, by the way raid checking is still not finished

Comment: What you added about CPU consumption was that there wasn't much. And you said you "suspected" it was slowing your server. So, to be 100% clear, you aren't actually seeing any performance issues. Is that correct?

Comment: my services are failing when load goes above 7, and some processes are stooped like backup, so it is enough to suspect. I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: Can you update your question with that information then? What services are failing? What processes are stopped? Have you done any investigation into why? High load average should be harmless if it's low-priority I/O.

Comment: There's always some twit who never ever contributes wanting the question reworded to satisfy their ego. sigh. Google shows this as the top answer to a search of "raid resync cpu" so the wording is  perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further examining I saw that sdb disk is having some warnings about firmware

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-9YN166
Serial Number:    W1F0M6VY
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0525256dd
Firmware Version: CC4B
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 26 19:49:32 2017 CEST

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en
```

After that I checked latency of both disks using Munin plugin which showed me that sdb had much higher latency than sda disk. After that I sent mail to my hosting provider and they have replaced this baracuda disk without any fee. So changing disk solved problem to me, although both disks appeared fine when tested and both passed tests.

Answer (score 3):

This is down (at least on CentOS 6, I don't have a C7 box to hand as `systemd` still gives me hives) to the file `/etc/cron.d/raid-check`.  This schedules a RAID scrub once a week.  It isn't supposed to conflict with real use of the HDDs, but even a perfectly submissive algorithm will still have some backoff time when the system IO steps up massively under new load.

You are free to run that job less often, or indeed not at all, by editing the file (or disabling in `/etc/sysconfig/raid-check`).  If you think you are having actual disc problems, it's probably best to disable it while you test the hypothesis (though make sure your backups are up-to-date and that you have tested your restores!).  Once you've determined what's going on, it's probably best to re-enable it.  I'd run it at least monthly.

Comment: my load averages now are 6.45 5.84 5.90, and none of processes is using too much CPU power, yesterday it was up to 8. Similar loads were also when this checking was not done. Is it normal that checking lasts so long and that raid uses so much CPU?

Comment: Lasts so long?  Yes, it must read and compare every single bit on two 3TB drives.  Particularly if these are SATA drives, that will take some hours.  Uses so much CPU?  It doesn't, but it *does* use IO capacity, and jobs blocked on IO are counted as being on the run queue.  The high load average is likely processes that are blocked on IO, not CPU.